# Hot reload developing Greasemonkey userscript

Tags: typescript, userscripts, hot-reload, yarnpkg-v2

I'm trying to make a userscript for script runner like (Tamper|Grease)monkey - that adds a script to page of specified URL.

Also I work with React, typescript etc. in other projects.

I wonder if it's possible to use Typescript to develop these userscripts and somehow use the live dev environment embedded to specific page.

Is it possible and how? Do you have experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as you few weeks ago. Found many projects on GitHub by searching [userscript template](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=userscript+template&s=updated&type=Repositories). But after awhile, I decided to create my own.

- [webpack-userscript-template](https://github.com/Trim21/webpack-userscript-template)
- [userscript-gulp-template (mine)](https://github.com/FlowerForWar/userscript-gulp-template)

There was a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/userscripts/comments/wlqoyz/best_template_for_developing_userscripts/) on Reddit few days ago, by someone who was asking the same question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32555664)

Comment: Good point. I'll update my answer.